# Is this equivalent to the infinity norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator from two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$.
Does it follow that, $$||T(x)||_{\infty} = \sup_{||x|| = 1}||T(x)|| =  M$$
is equivalent to showing $\forall x \in X$,
$$||T(x)|| \le M||x||.$$

Comment: What's $\lVert T(x)\rVert_\infty$?

Comment: $$||T(x)||_{\infty} = \sup_{||x|| = 1}||T(x)||$$

Comment: The latter is equivalent to $\| T \|_\infty \leq M$, not $\| T \|_\infty = M$. (The fact that you can swap between the definition in terms of the whole space and the definition in terms of the unit sphere is a consequence of linearity.)

Comment: @Ian I was trying to find the relationship. I see now, thanks.

Comment: Your second definition can be read as "$M$ is a Lipschitz-constant of $T$". However $\|T\|_\infty$ is the _smallest_ Lipschitz-constant, ie $\|T\|_\infty =\inf \{ M \mid \|Tx\|≤ M\|x\|\ \ \ \forall x\}$.